# spring annotation manage pojo

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I use spring annotation to manage java bean, use @service in service layer, and @autowired when inject service, but now I have a question, how to manage POJO by spring?

for example, I need to return a user for ajax call, so I need to always write like:

```
User user = new User()......
return user;
```

So, how I can use like

```
@autowired User user;
```

And the User POJO will be:

```
@component
@scope("prototype")
public class User{}
```

so each time the user entity will be a new one, and I needn't to new it everytime,
But I failed to write like this, so can spring manage POJO to be a prototype?

Update====================================
Thanks for answering

Comment: Have you an error message? Does User have a default constructor?

Comment: What do you mean by _failed to write like this_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options that i can think of straigh away. What you want is to be able to create prototypes from within a singleton. So you can either use..

1) AOP Scoped Proxy.
So change your User class annotation to ...

```
@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

(this required cglib on your classpath)

or

2) lookup-method
this is a bit more involved and makes things a bit harder to test

or

3) make your class implement ApplicationContextAware and then you can just call getBean on the context when you want a new prototype.

A bit of googling will sort you out anyway but I recommend the first option

Comment: @dectain, thanks for your answer, I declare POJO Bean as you said, but now I meet another issue, when sever try to return the POJO Bean to client, there is an error, "No serializer found for class org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.user_center.beans.RestResponse$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$90b60696["callbacks"])", and I've add JsonSerialize annotation above the POJO Bean

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class User 
{
 ......
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How is that different than what they have?